# bind custom code formatter to eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, project, formatter

I have a custom code formatter that I have set in my Java projects. All code changes get automatically formatted on save. My projects are saved via SVN on a server, so others can work on them as well.

The problem is that I want to have a single code formatter (mine) to be applied on all machines. The way it is now, I have to go to a new machine, check out the code (the formatter is in the repository as well), import the project to eclipse and manually change the eclipse settings to use that code formatter. Is there a way to do that on project level instead of IDE level? So I don't have to do this manually on every machine?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open the context menu of the project -> Properties -> Java Code Style -> Formatter. Check "Enable Project specific settings" and configure the profile.

All the important Java related settings are available on a per project base and you should *never* modify Java related settings through Window -> Preferences, if you share the project with others. Project properties are saved *in* your project (and therefore shared with all), preferences are stored *far away and unrelated* to your project.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I was looking for. I will check it shortly.

Comment: Ok, the code style formatter seems to be the same on all machines now. Perfect. Though on the all machines (except the one that formatter was created), it says *Unmanaged Profile "NameOfMyProfile"*. What does that mean?

Comment: That's probably not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266032/how-do-i-manage-an-unmanaged-eclipse-formatting-profile

Comment: Ah, I see. That's actually exactly what I want. I should be the only one able to change the code format. Very good. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to ask the development team to use common IDE e.g eclipse and I believe similar sort of rules are applicable in eclipse while formatting the code.It seems your development team is using different IDE's.

Comment: No, we are all using eclipse. But I want to use a custom code formatter and not the default one. I can't figure out how to save that in the project instead of manually setting it on every machine.

Answer (score -2):

Temporary solution could be to keep a copy of eclipse (with your settings and customization) in common place e.g.FTP or wherever you want,say if a new developer is to join the team all he has do is get that already configured eclipse and start working.

Comment: Its pretty clear from the question thats not what he is expecting.